# Play a video source, after setTimeout function is done

Tags: asynchronous, video, html5-video, settimeout, svelte

I would like to show a splash image over top of an HTML Video for about 3 seconds. My thought is to have the splash image show initially, then a use setTimeout function to turn the splash image off after 3 seconds. It seems that a setTimeout runs WHILE the rest of the script runs which I didn't know. So I sometimes get a black placeholder first because the video source loads so quickly, before even the splash. (Also Trust that I get the splash image and video source from somewhere) Thanks!

```js
let videoUri: string;
let splashImg: string = ...
let showSplash: boolean = true;

//time out function...
const displaySplashScreen = () => {
  showSplash = true;
  console.log('this runs first');
  setTimeout(() => {
    showSplash = false;
    console.log('this runs last');
  }, 3000);
  console.log('this runs second???')
};

//Check if src changes, do a thing...
$: if(src){
  displaySplashScreen()
}

//Run timeout on initial mount...
onMount(()=>{
  displaySplashScreen()
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video src={videoUri} />
  {#if showSplash}
    <img src={splashImg} />
  {/if}
<div/>
```

```css
.container{
  height:300px;
  width:500px
}

video{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this work

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  let videourl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/rBLCjz8as0E";
  let imgUrl =
    "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e8/a4/b7/e8a4b72e36b171edc1c52de654609fa3.jpg";
  let show = true;
  let displaySplash = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      show = false;
    }, 3000);
  };
  onMount(() => {
    displaySplash();
  });
</script>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    {#if show === false}
      <iframe
        width="560"
        height="315"
        src={videourl}
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
      />
    {:else}
      <img src={imgUrl} alt="" />
    {/if}
  </div>
</main>

<style>
  .container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
  }

  video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This basically works, now i need to figure out how to trigger and clear old timeout when changing the src too. cant do it in onmount though...

Comment: What do you mean you can't do it in onmount? The variables are reactive, so if you cahnge the values, it will trigger the changes again. You can just set `show = true` again, and create another timeout that does the same exact thing.